# routing between MacOS Sonoma interfaces

Tags: macos, network

MacBook Air M2 Sonoma 14.4

After a couple of days trying different solutions I've read, time to ask here.

Have a RPi 4 connected to MacBook through USB Ethernet adapter en5.
Uses DHCPCD, but fails over to static 192.168.8.100 255.255.255.0 192.168.8.1 configuration, if it can't find DHCP server.
Can connect to it through ssh either way from the Mac.

MacBook is connected to the Internet via WiFi en0 to a business router 192.168.1.1 and gets dhcp address 192.168.1.77.
Reaches Internet properly.
Can ping all involved IPs successfully, including the RPi.

Can't get the RPi to reach the Internet through the MacBook.

I tried to make InternetSharing work, but gave up after about half a day; I see  that the same bugs and limitations others described in it more than a decade ago are still here in the latest MacOS! (So, clear how little Apple cares about this feature working well...)

Installed dnsmasq successfully and got proper dhcp and dns from it to the RPi. It has dns resolution.
Nevertheless, the RPi still can't reach the Internet.

dnsmasq from homebrew doesn't seem to log anywhere, even though i enabled that in its config file.

Disabling ufw on RPi, MacOS firewall and VPN app - also not helpful.

I tried many static routing articles, but the RPi still can only ping the Mac's Ethernet interface IP 192.168.8.1. Pinging the Mac's WiFi interface 192.168.1.77 and the router 192.168.1.1 both fail from RPi, but succeed from the Mac.

So, the Mac knows how to route to the RPi, and the RPi can reach the Mac.

192.168.8.100(RPi eth0)<===>(Mac en5)192.168.8.1<== **X** ==>192.168.1.77(Mac en0)<===>(Router)

How to make the Mac forward all en5 traffic to en0?